# can I create a route that could be use both for serving HTML and REST API?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, isomorphic-javascript

Okay here's the scenario, to my knowledge there are three ways to create a web application

1. Traditional way: Render the HTML page from the server
2. Not sure: Create an API and let the user's browser to download the
   Javascript application (Angular, React, Ember) to get a highly
   interactive application
3. The future: Isomorphic web app, which render the HTML together with the client-side technologies (Angular, React, Ember) from the server.

I'm planning to use the third way, due to faster load page, but the problem right now is if I were about to create a mobile application.

My stack: Node.js + React

Let say if I'm planning to go mobile, do i need to duplicate the same route and logic ? 
Current problem

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index', { message: "Hey Im Jack" });
});

app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
   res.json({ message: "Hey Im Jack" })
});
```

Is there any way that I could use to for one route to serve both the HTML and REST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ultimately only send either HTML or JSON (in case of REST).

The /api/xxx route syntax makes it clearer which path serves the JSON.

But you can depend on client's request header to check whether they requested JSON or HTML

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    if (req.headers.accept && req.headers.accept.match(/json/))
        res.json(data);
    else
        res.render('index', data);
});
```

[Angular's $http usually requests json by default](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers), not sure about others, but you can set the headers. Browsers normally request text/html, but I'm not sure.

Or if you're only concerned about not having to repeat the logic that fetches the data, you could put a middleware preceeding both:

```
// regex to match both routes
app.get(/.*users/, function(req, res) {
   res.locals.data = { message: "Hey Im Jack" };
   req.next();
});

app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
   res.render('index', res.locals.data);
});

app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
   res.json(res.locals.data)
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, first does mobile have req.headers.accept.match() ? and the second solution , the regex probably is very redundant right? because let say I have 10 routes and all requires some mongodb query, then do I need to create another 10 additional middleware?

Comment: `req.headers` is a property of the [HTTP request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) made by the client, so it will definitely be present for all clients. [`.accept` may not be](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) actually, in which case you should so `req.headers.accept && req.headers.accept.match(…`.

Comment: The regex route's purpose was to have a middleware that runs for both: `/users` or `/api/users`. Since you said it would be redundant to write the code for presumably running the same query for both, this way that code can be run for both routes in a middleware preceding them both. If you have 10 routes that require the **same** mongodb query you would just need 1 such middleware preceding them all. If they're all different that require different query code then yeah, I don't see the purpose of that preceding middleware.

Comment: will try your solution, and see whether it scales or not. Thanks